# Identity element or neutral element in a Rubik's Cube

Tags: group-theory, rubiks-cube

I read that the Rubik's Cube is a permutation group. [Here](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/mathematics-of-the-rubiks-cube-permutation-group/), it says that "***Neutral Element*** - *there is a permutation which doesn't rearrange the set: ex. $RR'$  *" (For Rubik's Cube notations see [this.](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/notation/))

I know that for some mathematical structure, say $(S, \ast)$, the identity element is defined as $a\ast e = e \ast a = a$ where $e$ is the identity element $\forall\:a \in S$ and that $e$ is unique. For a Rubik's Cube, how is the identity element unique? For $D$, we have $D'$. For $F$ we have $F'$ and so on.

Comment: First of all, a Rubik cube is not a group. To say that it is is a little like saying that a person is a height. Next, $RR',DD',FF'$ and so on are all the same element of the group, just different ways to write it, much as $7-7,19-19,42-42$ are different ways to write the identity element in the additive group of integers.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. But why does it everywhere say that the Rubik's Cube is a permutation group?

Comment: Please show me where it says that.

Comment: @tomriddle99 Perhaps by ambiguity of language. What do we mean when we say "Rubik's cube"? A certain physical object?  The puzzle that asks us to bring said object into its standard state? The theory behind said puzzle? ...

Comment: @GerryMyerson visit the first link.

Comment: That link doesn't even use the word "group"!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm terribly sorry. I posted the wrong link. You can visit it now.

Comment: @GerryMyerson http://www.math.harvard.edu/~jjchen/docs/Group%20Theory%20and%20the%20Rubik%27s%20Cube.pdf#subsection.3.2  Here, they have established Rubik's Cube as a group.

Comment: @GerryMyerson How is the Rubik's Cube not a group? It is closed, it has an identity element, every transformation has an inverse since any sequence of actions can be performed in reverse), and (I think) it is associative. Also Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group

Comment: @tomriddle99 You can define the Rubik's cube group as the being the set of every possible transformation. The group can be generated by the basic transformations (e.g. rotations, turning a slice, etc.). You can index all 48 squares and define permutations on the vector.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler I was convinced it was a group. I was just confused about the identity element. It was specified here, http://www.math.harvard.edu/~jjchen/docs/Group%20Theory%20and%20the%20Rubik%27s%20Cube.pdf#subsection.3.2, just as you said.

Comment: It's crazy isn't it. You have the group of permutations of 48-dim integer vectors, which is huge by itself, but then it has all of these fascinating subgroups. I wish I had  more time to get into group theory. I love how these hidden, rich structures like the Rubik's cube are secretly embedded in these ginormous unparsable structures.

Comment: They are being very sloppy. A group has elements. A cube doesn't, so a cube is not a group. A cube *has* a group of symmetries, but it isn't, itself, a group. A person has a height, but a person isn't a height. It is important in mathematics to use terms precisely and accurately.

Comment: In the notes on the Harvard website, Section 3.2 is headed, Making the Rubik Cube into a Group, but then the first senstence that follows says "We can make the set of moves of the Rubik’s cube into a group...." The headline is sloppy, the sentence is correct: it's the moves that form a group, not the cube itself.

Comment: If you say the cube is a group, you may as well say that a square matrix is a determinant, and a vector space is a basis, and a polynomial is a root, and a circle is a diameter, and so on, and so forth.

Comment: Accuracy is even more important in puzzles like the 4x4x4 Rubik's cube. It has an associated permutation group, but this group has more elements than there are cube states, because the cube has some indistinguishable pieces. At least on the 3x3x3 cube there is a one-to-one correspondence between cube states and group elements (the group [*acts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)) on the cube states, and this action is *faithful*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity element is simply doing nothing to the Rubik's Cube. If you indexed every face on the cube, doing nothing to the cube would result in the identity permutation where nothing changes.

Comment: Please change it as $\color{green}{\text{Rubik's}}$